# VBA - workaround for conditionally calling a function with certain optional parameters?

Tags: vba

Consider a function with several optional parameters. E.g.:

```VBA
Function foo(Optional a, Optional b, Optional c, Optional d)
```

If I want to call the specific function only with the arguments are not null, or some other test, (because the function raises an error otherwise, **unless the argument is missing**).

An example would be the Collection class. There are 3 optional parameters to the Add method. Many custom classes wrap this class - such as to create an indexable class Persons of a 'Person' custom class or something like that. A wrapper has to deal with 6 combinations: adding a Key only, adding a Key and specifying Before, adding a Key and specifying After, not adding a Key and specifying Before, not adding a Key and specifying After, no Key and no Before/After. It would get even worse if writing a wrapper to something like Workbook.Save that has a dozen Optional parameters.

I am not aware of an alternative to some tedious construct like:

```VBA
If a <> Null Then
    If b <> Null Then
        If c <> Null Then
            If d <> Null Then
                foo a, b, c, d
            Else
                foo a, b, c
            End If
        Else
            If d <> Null Then
                foo a, b, d
            Else
                foo a, b
            End If
        End If
    Else
    '... Etc ...
```

Clearly the number of nested Ifs and general code overhead roughly doubles for each additional optional variable.

In .NET there is the type System.Type.Missing that can be passed in, allowing the expression to be a lot more simple.

Like in C# it can be as clean as:

```C#
foo(a ?? Missing, b ?? Missing, c ?? Missing, d ?? Missing);
```

(this says 'if a is null then pass in Missing (or perhaps behind the scenes it refactors the call itself), a call equivalent to not passing in anything for the optional argument a, and etc)

And if it were implemented, an equivalent could be in VBA using in-line iff ('IIF(boolean, true, false)')

Is there a workaround for VBA that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to use `ParamArray`?

Comment: Except if each parameter has a different type (integer, boolean, string, etc...) how do you wanna know which parameter is which ?
How du you want to manage your parameters in Foo() ?

Comment: You have defined each parameter as variant. So, you can check inside `foo` function if parameter is missing by using `IsMissing(var)` function. Please, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251721.aspx

Comment: @MaciejLos it is a call to an external function (i.e. not a custom function). I have no control over how the function deals with the arguments, only what arguments are passed in. A missing argument is fine, but if it is specified then it cannot be null/nothing/anything I can think of that I could otherwise use in an in-line if.

Comment: Hmm - possibly you could workaround by using Call by name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(On edit: I incorporated HarveyFrench's improvement of the code)

You can make it a little less nested:

```
Function foo(Optional a, Optional b, Optional c, Optional d)
    Dim passed As String
    If Not IsMissing(a) Then passed = "a "
    If Not IsMissing(b) Then passed = passed & "b "
    If Not IsMissing(c) Then passed = passed & "c "
    If Not IsMissing(d) Then passed = passed & "d "
    foo = IIf(Len(passed) = 0, "Nothing ", passed) & "passed"
End Function

Function foo_dispatcher(Optional a, Optional b, Optional c, Optional d)
    Dim caseNum As Long
    caseNum = IIf(IsNull(a) Or IsEmpty(a) Or IsMissing(a), 0, 8)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(b) Or IsEmpty(b) Or IsMissing(b), 0, 4)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(c) Or IsEmpty(c) Or IsMissing(c), 0, 2)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(d) Or IsEmpty(d) Or IsMissing(d), 0, 1)

    Select Case caseNum
        Case 0: foo_dispatcher = foo()
        Case 1: foo_dispatcher = foo(, , , d)
        Case 2: foo_dispatcher = foo(, , c)
        Case 3: foo_dispatcher = foo(, , c, d)
        Case 4: foo_dispatcher = foo(, b)
        Case 5: foo_dispatcher = foo(, b, , d)
        Case 6: foo_dispatcher = foo(, b, c)
        Case 7: foo_dispatcher = foo(, b, c, d)
        Case 8: foo_dispatcher = foo(a)
        Case 9: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, , , d)
        Case 10: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, , c)
        Case 11: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, , c, d)
        Case 12: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, b)
        Case 13: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, b, , d)
        Case 14: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, b, c)
        Case 15: foo_dispatcher = foo(a, b, c, d)
    End Select
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(Null, Null, Null, Null)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(Null, 1, Null, 2)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(1, 2, 3, 4)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher()
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(, 1, , 2)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(a:=1, d:=Null)
End Sub
```

Output of `test`:

```
Nothing passed
b d passed
a b c d passed
Nothing passed
b d passed
a passed
```

Obviously the actions in the 16 cases can be tailored to the calling convention of `foo` (e.g. you can dispatch to `foo(a,d)` rather than `foo(a,,,d)` if you need). I didn't check all 16 cases explicitly but it seems to work. What I did was somewhat mechanical. You can write a dispatch-generator - a function which takes a string function name, an array of required parameters, an array of optional parameters, and a value which plays the role of `Null` and returns a the dispatcher as a string which can be copy-pasted from the immediate window to a code module. I thought of doing that here but it didn't seem worth it for a proof-of-concept dispatcher.

Comment: Please see me comments in my answer.  I suggest you might modify you code to incorporate my suggestions

Comment: @HarveyFrench Thanks for the suggestion. It requires that the arguments of foo_dispatcher itself to be `Optional` now, which is a change for the better. `foo_dispatcher(,,,)` is a syntax error but `foo_dispatcher()` works correctly.

Comment: I'm a bit uncomfortable about Null being treated like a missing or empty value.  personally I think foo should handle Null being passed as a value if it is accepting variants!  nice bit of code to get around "crappy vba"

Comment: @HarveyFrench The null was an example so I could highlight the sharp difference with the clean Type.Missing using the null coelescing operator compared to VBA. The ultimate would be to workaround the whole 'missing' stupidity - none of my own classes use missing instead always using features of the type itself (Nothing, Empty, Null etc). Really it is looking for some way to avoid explicitly setting out the various combinations of calling a method with different optional arguments specified. Given that we have to deal with what we have, I think your answer is a good way of streamlining it.

Comment: Thank you for this - a decent way of making the inelegance a bit more streamlined and greatly superior to nested Ifs. I looked into CallByName but it was fruitless as it can't deal with Optional arguments in this context. VB6 seems to have a way (using the invoker) but VBA cannot use it.

Answer (score 4):

John Coleman's answer is "as nice as VBA will get"

I think the foo_dispatcher will also need the following modification to the code (in many cases):

```
Function foo_dispatcher(a, b, c, d)

    Dim caseNum As Long

    caseNum = IIf(IsNull(a) or IsEmpty(a) or IsMissing(a), 0, 8)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(b) or IsEmpty(b) or IsMissing(b), 0, 4)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(c) or IsEmpty(c) or IsMissing(c), 0, 4)
    caseNum = caseNum + IIf(IsNull(d) or IsEmpty(d) or IsMissing(d), 0, 4)

    ' ...
```

and the test cases should also include

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(,,,)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(, 1, , 2)
    Debug.Print foo_dispatcher(a:=1,d:=Null)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a good modification of the code. I will add it in (with the final two 4's replace by the intended 2 and 1)

Comment: I'm glad someone is awake!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. See my comments above, and marked the joint effort as you say as "nice as VBA will get" :)